# How to cut naked domain in output?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

I want to cut url to terminal output but it returns several times same domain
I can cut https://blabla.domain.com with this

```
grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+'
```

But I want delete repeat of same domain and http:// tag.

my output is:

> https://blabla.domain.com
> https://blabla.domain.com
> https://blabla.domain.com
> https://blabla.domain.com

Comment: You can pipe your input to `sort` and `uniq` to filter identical rows. Something like `grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+' | sort | uniq`

Comment: Not worked, nothing happened and itsread any text from file

kaandikec@kaandikec-server:~$ grep -Eo text.txt'(http|https)://[^/"]+' | sort | uniq
http://test.com
http://test.com

^C
kaandikec@kaandikec-server:~$

Comment: @KAANDİKEÇ please click [edit] and add a few sample lines from `text.txt` for us to test.. as well as complete expected output for that sample

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to change this command to provide input. Something like `grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+' test.txt | sort | uniq` or `cat test.txt | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+' | sort | uniq`. Otherwise, input will be read from stdin and result will be printed when you send EOF (usually by Ctrl+D).